# Flutter: GoogleSignInAccount The property 'authentication' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, googlesigninaccount

I'm new to flutter. Am practicing google account log in.
When I define GoogleSignInAccount, there is an error: "A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'."

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
```

Other people saying that we can use '?' to solve this problem.
It works. However, another issue pop up: "The property 'authentication' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'."

```
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
```

Any advice would be great. ty

Comment: try googleUser!.authentication

Comment: @Pranav this and the other answer both work! thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that warning because **googleUser** has a **nullable** type (`GoogleSignInAccount?`) in order to use it in googleAuth you can mark it with a **bang (null-aware) operator** like this `googleUser!.authentication;`. However, only use that approach if you are 100% certain this will never be null, in which case you could simply use a non-nullable type (without the "?") if possible.

Alternatively, you can use `control flow statements` to only initialize googleAuth once googleUser is initialized with a non-null value.

**For example a null-check like this:**

```
if(googleUser !=null) {
   final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
}
```

**More context:**

The reason why you get the error: `"A value of type 'GoogleSignInAccount?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'GoogleSignInAccount'."` is that  `_googleSignIn.signIn();` has a **nullable** return type of `'GoogleSignInAccount?'`(because it can fail and don´t return a user), hence you cant assign it to a **non-nullable variable** with the type `'GoogleSignInAccount'.`

**FYI: It most likely makes more sense to add the null check around the _googleSignIn.signIn();**

Comment: this and the other comment both work! Those information is very useful for me. Thank you!